# Java - getting error on Hashmap.put

Tags: java, debugging, hashmap

I wrote a simple program in JAVA having 4 classes:

Main - > CarFaxApp

GUI / Logic - > CarFaxFrame

Object -> Car

Validator -> CarFaxValidator

Once the program is running and I start to enter the necessary data in the textbox's for the `car (String vin, String make, String model, int year)`. Everything works fine, but when I hit buttonADD(), I get a error.

`private HashMap<String,Car>hmCar; //Hashmap to hold Cars, the key pair value consists of (Vin, Car Object)`

The error happens on `hmCar.put(car.getVin(), car);` which I dont understand why, I tried debugging up to the point and car does hold the correct values.

Here a screen shot of the error:

[image]

Comment: It could very well be your `getVin()` function

Comment: Can `hmCar` be `null` at that point?

Comment: I tried replacing getVin() with vin only. Still happens

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes hmCar could be null at this point, but why would this matter if its a hashmap()?

Comment: You cannot call a method on `null` object. This will **always** produce NPE.

Comment: @PM77-1 The problem was my hashmap was still null and was never initialized as a new hashmap.

Answer (score 2):

the error is NullPointException, are you sure you do this

`hmCar = new HashMap<String, Car>();`

before you put the entry in.